# Possible sock puppet at Area 51

Tags: support, status-completed, area-51, sock-puppets

Look at the [comments here](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/17523/dmv-guide):

> US-only (now). I do not know whether other countries also call it dmv. How do I update the description? – 51local ↵ 6 hours ago
>
> 51local - do you see an edit button under the description? I assume you have the right to do that - if not post here what text you want and I (or someone else) will change it for you. – Mark Robinson ↵ 4 hours ago
>
> Thanks Mark. I have updated it. – dmv51 ↵ 6 mins ago

Two usernames in dialogue with Mark?

Comment: Wow - I got a mention in a meta question! *Slight feeling of pride.* More seriously, the dmv51 comment has gone now. Don't know if that is significant.

Comment: @Mark: It can't *always* be Jon Skeet :p

Comment: @Tobias: =:-) Seriously, here is more evidence for the sock puppet theory: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/17678/brain-teasers-iq-questions-and-answers

Comment: @Mark: I only see that these two are the only followers, where there comments before?

Comment: @Tobias - sorry, I don't understand your question.

Comment: @Mark: sorry, I meant "were there..." as in when you said there's more evidence did you only mean that these two users are the followers or was there something else I don't see?

Comment: @Tobias - only that those two are the only ones collaborating on that site which is quite a coincidence. Has the software flagged anything unusual?

Comment: @Mark: I don't know, we'd have to ask a mod. But I flagged one of the proposals for attention, maybe something will happen

Comment: @Tobias, OK good one.

Comment: Hmmm. Same user that posted this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60766/will-stackexchange-network-fail ?

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/9drlz.jpg

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We've merged all his accounts and sent him a warning email to not create any more accounts.  We won't delete his posts quite yet because:

1. A few others have committed to them
2. They appear to have been proposed with good intentions (actually wanting the sites to be made, not just trolling)

We'll keep an eye on his activity.  If necessary, we can suspend him / ban his IP but don't want to do that without some warning.

Comment: Thanks David for the reply. But I'm still puzzled why the software didn't pick up on this. Does the detection work differently on each site?

Comment: @David - and *have* you warned him?

Comment: @Mark The checks are mostly around users trying to use sock puppets to gain rep.  They didn't turn anything up here because he/she wasn't voting very much.

Comment: @Mark yes, we sent a warning email today

Comment: @David - thanks for the replies. Probably worth considering a new sock puppet detection algorithm for Area 51 if this occurs again.

Comment: Is his proposal-creating ability at least temporarily suspended? He has, after all, created 19 proposals in his 15 days of membership, and he also has asked more than five example question e.g. at [BT](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/17678/brain-teasers-iq-questions-and-answers).

Answer (score 10):

Sure looks like sock puppetry to me.  What are the odds that **seven** users who all just registered in the last 12 days are following nearly identical proposals that have almost nothing to do with each other?

Just look at this follower crossover:

```
════════════╬ Int'l Biz │ BT  │ DMV │ Local │ Fish/Hunt | H&H | WHH | Outdoor
living well ║    ●      │  ●  │     │       │           |  ●  |     |
petlover    ║    ●      │  ●  │  ●  │       │           |  ●  |  ●  |
dmv51       ║    ●      │  ●  │  ●  │   ●   │     ●     |     |     |
user16481   ║           │     │  ●  │       │     ●     │     │  ●  │    ●
outdoor     ║    ●      │  ●  │  ●  │   ●   │     ●     │     │  ●  |    ●
bbc101      ║    ●      │     │  ●  │   ●   │     ●     │  ●  │  ●  |    ●
51local     ║    ●      │  ●  │  ●  │   ●   │     ●     │  ●  │  ●  |    ●
```

What's more, *all* of these users have *created* at least one of the proposals and submitted questions on several of them.

I think our "white-hat hacker" is clearly trying to spam proposals and questions.  Even if there's no cross-voting going on (and I sincerely doubt that), this idiot is still blatantly trying to game the system.

Some of these users also have newer proposals with fewer followers (like Family, "Life Experiences", API Application Development); don't be too surprised if other users suddenly "stumble upon" those new proposals and start following them too!

Oh, and couple with the fact that all of these users suddenly start materializing 12 days ago - the **exact** same day that our friend posted his [Will the Stack Exchange Network fail?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60766/will-stackexchange-network-fail) discussion whining about not getting enough activity on his proposals - makes you think, dunnit?

Ban this f***er and delete his proposals!

Comment: @Aarobot - nice answer, especially the researched table. But doesn't the software have a way to detect this?

Comment: @Mark: Theoretically yes, but that's not to say that somebody determined enough couldn't find a way to stay just under the threshold.  The users were all registered on different days, posted questions in different proposals, and probably only voted a few times.  I think the system is designed to find 1 or 2 sock puppets on 1 master account, not 10 sock puppets all on random subsets of each other's accounts.  (Disclaimer: I have no inside knowledge of the algorithms used on Area 51)

Comment: I also flagged a few of his proposals directly for moderator attention, but nothing has happened so far

Comment: Well, it seems that this is not just any user with these sock puppets but someone who knows how to play the system.

Comment: (S)he's still at it! http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/19329/crowd-ideas **Hello, administrators?**

Comment: @Mark: There's also [Leadership](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/17814/leadership) and [Who did what](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/18955/who-did-what).  This guy's not going to quit until he's sh!tcanned.

Comment: I can't understand why 1. the admins haven't stepped in yet and blocked him and 2. why his IP address(es) haven't been blocked yet. **Please would more people flag this issue** - otherwise it might look like I'm nagging!

Comment: @Mark: Looks like they did an account merge.  Unfortunately that means he gets to keep all his proposals and have more than 5 questions in the proposals he really spammed hard (like Brain Teasers).  Oh well.

Comment: @Aarobot - thanks for the reply. That leaves me with two questions - 1. Why don't the moderators reply here? You know, "Thanks for flagging this, we've done...". 2. How come the moderators didn't delete all his account and his proposals and let him start from scratch (or ban him for a period)? Weird.

Comment: @Mark: You should probably e-mail the team.  Looks like David was the one that took care of this.  Maybe they thought his content was too valuable to delete, I don't know.

Comment: @Aarobot - I tried hunting for their email addresses - apparently not enough because I could only find team@stackoverflow. Should I be looking for a meta address?

Comment: @Mark: That's the address.  It's the same team.

Comment: @Aarobot - thanks, email sent. Nice bit of research, above, btw.

Comment: @Aarobot - and David simultaneously posts an answer below... =:-)

Answer (score 6):

I don't yet know the answer but you have to admit: if one is a sock puppet it's pretty daft to have such similar names...

However, they **are** both following exactly the same Q&As, so it seems likely that they are either the same person or two people with a telepathic link.

**Update:** could be that he's added a new sock puppet: http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/16197/outdoor check out watch list. How come the software has not picked this up yet? Evidence:

- dmv51 posts [Fishing and Hunting](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/17899/fishing-and-hunting)
- outdoor posts [outdoor activities](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/17911/outdoor-activities), *the very next Q&A*, the description of which includes, **"hunting, fishing"**!

**Update 2:** check out the followers on both the proposals above - I have no doubt they are sock puppets.

**Update 3:** it's kind of hard to believe this so I'll just state what happened. Some went to my [Wikispeedia](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/13716/wikispeedia) Area 51 proposal and voted "not a good example" to *all five* of my questions and then, moments later "another user" voted one of them down as well. Coincidence or sock puppets? Since all five down votes happened in the same minute, I suspect not. Maybe an administrator can take a look?

Comment: I've flagged this for moderator attention, since nothing seems to have happened so far.

Comment: Robinson: So did I, I guess it needs more attention, or more evidence. I don't know...

Comment: Thanks Tobias - maybe we just need to keep plugging? I thought (from Pekka's comments) that the software should have flagged this a long time ago but apparently not. Thanks also for accepting this answer.

Comment: Also see the comments here: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/18054/white-hat-hacking. Looks like Robert changed the name of the proposal, but originally, "outdoor" chimed in in place of 51local to defend the name.

Comment: @Aarobot - thanks again for the info - this is *so sad* (i.e. pathetic).

Answer (score 3):

`dmv51`'s only activity has been on the DMV proposal he made, and `51local`'s only activity on the "Local things" proposal he made, so it looks like the user is just trying to keep a separate account for each proposal he's active on. I'm not sure why you would do that, but it doesn't seem malicious

Comment: well, it allowed him two proposals on one day (and he could theoretically upvote himself)

Comment: @Tobias true, but the engine has mechanisms to detect cross-upvotes like that.

Comment: @Tobias Ah, I didn't realize there was a one proposal/day limit

Comment: Both "users" have made another proposal today. It really seems a bit fishy to me

Comment: Indeed, this could be malicious, but I'm giving the benefit of the doubt here... maybe he's just confused and thinks you're supposed to create a new username for each site, or something.

Comment: @Pekka - I have my doubts about your confidence in the engine...

Comment: @Mark In my experience, it works fine on SO proper - but I don't know about the other SE sites...

Answer (score 3):

Another one: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/17911/outdoor-activities/17992#17992

[image: cheater?]

51local once again replies in lieu of the proposal owner. suspicious...

Comment: Yep, agreed - see my comments above.