# Downtime alert in Google Chrome

Tags: support, downtime

Practically all SE sites I tried, except Meta, are failing to load for me, with the exception of MSO.

[image]

Additionally, all chats are offline and MSO's visit chat acknowledges this by not advertising any room.

---

> ### Rebuild full-text catalog In progress ...
>
> <sub>[waffles](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/225708#225708)</sub>

Comment: Yeah, I also tried downforeveryoneorjustme ;)

Comment: Area51 is up, though.

Comment: The hamsters powering the server farm finally gave up.

Comment: The blog also appears down. Now where do we go and complain about the down time?

Comment: Where's Jeff Atwood?

Comment: Additionally, shouldn't this be tagged `[bug]` ? ;)

Comment: [҉](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ov9_5a5Ssms&feature=related)

Comment: THE WEB SITE! IT DOES NOTHING! P.S. Thanks for posting so I didn't have to.

Comment: Well, it [DOES SOMETHING](http://stackoverflow.com/error) again for me.

Comment: [The Tavern](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89/the-tavern-general) is alive again

Comment: [Yippee!](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Nooo, my 30-day consecutive login silver badge is in the mercy of ISP power issues!

Comment: StackOverflow.com is still down for me. ServerFault.com won't log me in... and I can't vote on SuperUser. I think I'll go do some chores and come back later today ;-)

Comment: how much time will take for repair?

Comment: @user152148 - I'm hoping they cover this for the users affected: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67109/proposal-free-day-in-the-visit-log-to-account-for-the-oct-9th-downtime

Comment: *@TheUnhandled*: It shouldn't matter as long as the badge code is counting dates "properly" (i.e. based on the server being up).

Comment: It affected me. I was on 98 consecutive days. I tried to log in when the site was down and next time I logged in, I was on 1 consecutive day. This is not good enough.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

<strike>The database is "suspect" we are running through our disaster recovery plans.</strike>

The power outage took the db into a suspect mode. After we recovered it the full text index was corrupt beyond recovery.

<strike>We rebuilt it from scratch and all should be good now.</strike>

We lost 4 hours of data, and are working on recovering it at the moment

Comment: It's still acting up for me. I get the front page in high speed, but nothing beyond that. The requests all time out

Comment: I'm getting 500's when editing as well here

Comment: By the way, I would have found it much more fitting if Meta's database had been marked "Suspect". Because that one really is, even when it's not broken :)

Comment: Has the team considered any kind of redundant power solution, so in case of a power failure, the system could at least shut down gracefully?

Comment: Are there some data lost? I've lost 3 upvotes today.

Comment: Actually, it's not that upvotes are lost, but *questions* are gone, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3896462/c-programming-language-increment-decrement-operators and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3896071/why-is-this-python-operation-returning-a-tuple

Comment: @KennyTM - See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67110/data-loss-due-to-downtime

Answer (score 14):

*Update #4 (13:17 Zulu):* There appear to be lingering issues with posting/editing at least, possibly other areas, site is offline again.

*Update #3 (12:58 Zulu):* Looks like SO is back online: https://stackoverflow.com/

*Update #2 (10:54 Zulu):* Getting the SO error page now, she breathes!

*Update #1 (10:50 Zulu):* [Confirmed on twitter](http://twitter.com/#!/SuperDalgas/statuses/26833250675) by @[Geoff Dalgas](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/2/geoff-dalgas):

> StackOverflow is down - ISP power issues - we will be back up soon

---

Remember that meta was migrated to NYC recently, so it's still up, looks like everything in the old datacenter is offline at the moment, for whatever reason :)

- stackoverflow.com - 69.59.196.211
- serverfault.com - 69.59.196.211
- superuser.com - 69.59.196.211

These (and most of the other sites) are all being routed through the HA Proxy in the old datacenter.

- meta.stackoverflow.com - 64.34.119.12
- area51.stackexchange.com - 64.34.119.12

These sites are in the NYC (new) datacenter, and still online.

Comment: Looks like you have an extra Server Fault in there.

Comment: Hah! What did I say. It was the hamsters.

Answer (score 7):

Hmmm, there's one good thing about this downtime. I never knew Chrome does this:

> Other users are also **experiencing difficulties** connecting to this site, so you may have to **wait a few minutes.**

It actually doesn't show this on my Mac, but surely it tells Google which sites I visit? So, [Google Chrome Is The New “Down For Everyone Or Just Me”](http://techcrunch.com/2010/08/31/chrome-downforeveryoneorjustme/). This indeed seems to be part of the privacy setting for "[Suggestions for navigation errors](http://www.google.com/support/chrome/bin/answer.py?answer=114836)":

> In order to offer suggestions of alternative or similar webpages, the browser sends Google the URL of the page you're trying to reach whenever the web address does not resolve or a connection cannot be made. Information is logged and anonymized in the same manner as [Google web searches](http://www.google.com/privacy_faq.html). Any parameters in the URL are removed before the URL is sent. The logs are used to ensure and improve the quality of the feature.

Comment: It doesn't show it for me on Windows 7. It could be because I have phoning-home option disabled (see privacy options).

Comment: This kind of thing is exactly why I stopped using Chrome. Who knows what else it's doing that I _don't_ find out about?

Answer (score 5):

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Another good thing about the downtime.  It prompted me to move my flair over to the new image based system. The old flair was causing all my pages that used it to redirect to the SO 404 page ;).

Answer (score 1):

Now i get the

> **Stack Overflow is currently offline for maintenance**
>   [image]

while ServerFault and SuperUser are working fine now..