# A status page showing whether SO and other SE network sites are up and running

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, downtime

[Current prolonged downtime](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/67088/95) made me realize that StackExchange needs a page showing status of all network sites similar to [Twitter Status](http://status.twitter.com/) or [Last.fm Status](http://status.last.fm/).

Such page would **a single place** to post information about planned maintenance windows ([example](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/12/scheduled-site-maintenance-saturday/)), quick updates during unplanned outages ([example](http://twitter.com/SuperDalgas/statuses/26833250675)) and maybe statistics from some website monitoring service. It should have **simple address**.

It has to be **hosted in a different datacenter than the ones used by SE sites or use a 3rd party service** (e.g. Twitter uses Tumblr for this).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### StackStatus has arrived!

Since November 2012 the updates on Stack Exchange Network outages and maintenance windows can be found on:

- https://www.stackstatus.net/
- Twitter: https://twitter.com/StackStatus

Answer (score 5):

I can see the necessity of a "heartbeat monitor" for a  telephone network like Skype when you're dealing with a complex, worldwide network and thousands of local phone exchanges, but for a Q&A network, it sounds like overkill. But a simple status page (like the Last.fm one) sounds like a nice idea.

That could be achieved simply by hosting the blog outside the rest of the network (at a physically different location) so it is available even if everything else goes down. (If that's not the case already. I didn't check whether it was affected by the outage as well, but the IPs look like they're in the same data center.)

Comment: I agree I put too much pressure on the *real-time heartbeat* aspect originally, I've just edited my question.

Comment: server fault blog is hosted by tumblr, so I'd check there.

Comment: @Jeff the natural inclination of most users will be top check on blog.stackoverflow.com, though - also because the error page advises them to do so

Comment: @Pekka And they should trust this inclination - http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/stack-overflow-outage-2/!

Comment: @Marek yeah, but I think it was down during the power failure, so it has little value as a "status" page. It's not a big deal either way - it shouldn't be a problem for anybody to simply wait until the sites are up again - but if there *is* to be a status page that runs independently from the network, the SO blog would be the much more natural choice.

Comment: @Pekka I know it was down during the power failure. I was being ironic! I have no idea why Jeff tells us to use http://blog.serverfault.com/ as status page when it still has no information about today's problem.

Answer (score 0):

http://blog.serverfault.com is hosted on Tumblr, so check there.

And note that Kyle and George work for SOIS, Inc as our system administrators -- so they'd be well positioned to tell you what's going on..

Comment: I'm sure the explanation will be posted there finally. But when it comes to checking **current** SE network status, it's not very useful - it's been a few hours since the outage and http://blog.serverfault.com/ says nothing about it. I don't know why you tagged my question with `status-completed`; `status-declined` seems to be more appropriate.