# "Status" blog for StackExchange

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, downtime

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [A status page showing whether SO and other SE network sites are up and running](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67104/a-status-page-showing-whether-so-and-other-se-network-sites-are-up-and-running)

I think status blog like twitter has:

http://status.twitter.com/

This is a site that is constantly evolving and thus has many transitory bugs etc

Might be a good idea for avoiding 125 meta.stackoverflow.com comments on the same error!

Hope you like the idea...

Comment: No? not a good idea? :(

Answer (score 3):

### StackStatus has arrived!

Since November 2012 the updates on Stack Exchange Network outages and maintenance windows can be found on:

- Tumblr: https://www.stackstatus.net/
- Twitter: https://twitter.com/StackStatus