# Is http://stackexchange.com/ down ?

Tags: support, status-completed, stackexchange.com

when I try to load https://stackexchange.com/ it goes to the error page.  [image]

Comment: No repro here. It's probably random error on their server cluster that affects some users.

Comment: I get the same when going to "top % this month" at https://stackexchange.com/leagues/3/month/superuser/2015-02-01/337631#337631 or any other stackexchange.com link.

Comment: Looks down to me

Comment: Strange, everything works for me...

Comment: working fine for me too!

Comment: Ah now works fine for me :)

Comment: Just to update: Yes, it was down for some users. Should be good for now; we're still investigating the root cause.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We did have a period of issues with SE.COM on a few servers.  We have cleared out the failed build and it should be working as of this moment.

Answer (score 1):

You can always check the availability of Stack Exchange and Stack Overflow using [Stack Status](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/165095/215590).