# Link to "login with stack overflow" goes to error page on stack overflow carreers

Tags: bug

If in this page:
http://careers.stackoverflow.com/cv/get-one
[image: step 1]
I click the "try stack overflow" login button

I go to this page:
https://stackexchange.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/oauth
[image: step 2]

Comment: [stackexchange.com is giving that error on any page, for some users, but not for everyone.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250307/is-http-stackexchange-com-down) It gave me the same error earlier this week, but works for me now.

Comment: Looks to be the same problem as others have with other services. (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250307/is-http-stackexchange-com-down)