# Data loss due to downtime

Tags: bug

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Stack Overflow Outage](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67114/stack-overflow-outage)

Now that SO is back online it seems that all the history from my activity on the site today is lost. Are there backups? Will the history be restored?

Comment: I also noticed that stuff posted in the last 4 hours is not present.

Comment: Backups run at midnight, looks like the site was restored from the latest one.

Comment: @Nick: Yes, it looks like the oldest activity is from ~07:00 UTC, which probably means midnight somewhere in USA :)

Comment: @Daniel - SO's datacenter is located in Corvallis Oregon, so yep, that's inline with west coast midnight :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The team is working on recovering the data:

> ... We lost 4 hours of data, and are working on recovering it at the moment...
>
> Posted by [@waffles](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/17174/waffles) a few seconds ago: [Downtime alert](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67088/downtime-alert/67092#67092)

Comment: The problem is that now they brought the site online without restoring data there could conflicts when later trying to restore the backup because existing questions could be modified and new data comes in.

Comment: I guess the `SO team` will have a bunch of questions to ask their own users :-)