# stackoverflow data loss on 9. oct '10=?

Tags: support, maintenance

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Data loss due to downtime](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67110/data-loss-due-to-downtime)
>   [Stack Overflow Outage](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67114/stack-overflow-outage)

hey there...

stackoverflow was in maintance mode for some time today.
now i accidently noticed that two comments on this answer have gone missing?
[How to select a period in mysql using the date field as a unix timestamp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3895055/how-to-select-a-period-in-mysql-using-the-date-field-as-a-unix-timestamp/3895127#3895127)

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67110/data-loss-due-to-downtime