# Why is it possible to vote on closed Area 51 proposals?

Tags: discussion, questions, area-51, voting, closed-proposals

Select any closed Area 51 proposal (e.g. [Getting Things Done](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/18970/getting-things-done)) - you can vote on any question.

Why is that? I would have thought that **closed** meant *"end of activity"*.

Comment: Heh... Assuming they based A51 on the SO engine, all "closed" means is "no more answers" (where answers are sample questions).

Comment: So, the conclusion is that the underlying code is different? I wonder if the sock puppet detection code is different as well... http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60660/possible-sock-puppet-at-area-51 =:-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably because a closed proposal can be reopend and the votes of bypassers who agree with that but would not return later could still help. Closed answers and questions can also be voted on here, test it by searching `closed:1 answers:1`. Closed only means no further answers can be posted.

Comment: Great answer Tobias: concise, clear and complete. Thanks.