# Clicking on the "Top X% this <time period>" link on profile pages on Area51 discuss returns 404

Tags: bug, area-51, reputation-leagues

Clicking on the rep league lines that read like "top 2% this quarter" returns a 404 page.

Example in point: https://stackexchange.com/leagues/90/quarter/discuss-area51/2016-07-01/109290#109290

This report is split off as per request of Adam Lear from [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/283434/to-review-or-not-to-review-that-is-the-question-aka-review-link-appears-even-t)

Comment: Well, there are no reputation leagues for Area 51, and there's [existing feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75072/reputation-leagues-for-area-51) to add them. IMO better just remove the link from the Area 51 profile pages.